# 2 checkbox to post with the same name?

Tags: html, checkbox

how can i do? the research "comment[]" is said to be used in this way. It gives an error when I do this

> $comment= post("comment");

```
           <input type="radio" value="1" name="comment">
           <label for="comment"> Yes</label>

           <input type="radio" value="2" name="comment">
           <label for="comment"> No</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form action="your_php.php" method="post">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="comment">
            <label for="comment"> Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" value="2" name="comment">
            <label for="comment"> No</label>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
    </form>
```

**your_php.php**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["comment"])) {
            $comment = $_POST["comment"];
}
            print_r($comment);

            ?>
```